# How to block PROPFIND (or any other method) on Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

How can I block PROPFIND (or other methods, such as PUT or DELETE) on my whole site with Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit) or LimitExcept directive. One example might be:

```
<Location />
<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler. Limit just one method instead of trying your shot in the dark about what methods are really needed to except.

```
<Limit PROPFIND>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Limit>
```