# What exactly are PROPFIND,PUT,DELETE requests and how can I use it?

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I send a PROPFIND, PUT, DELETE request myself for testing purposes? Any online tools like web-sniffer.net that can be used for this?

Also, it looks like some other people blocked it [How to block PROPFIND (or any other method) on Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/72683/how-to-block-propfind-or-any-other-method-on-apache) - is that advisable?

Looks like it is enabled by default on Apache

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` and `DELETE` are standard HTTP methods (see [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)), while `PROPFIND` is a WebDAV-specific method (see [RFC 4918](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4918.txt)) - `PUT` and `DELETE` are also used in WebDAV.

`PUT` uploads a resource, replacing an existing one.

`DELETE` ... deletes a resource.

`PROPFIND` is used to request properties, information about the resource.

For testing, you can just use a WebDAV client, send requests directly via a telnet session, or if you need to get a little more particular about crafting the requests, something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).